# Entity Framework - set model property value dynamically from a query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, code-first

I have the following models:

```
public class A_DTO
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    **public virtual B_DTO B { get; set; }**

    public virtual List<B_DTO> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B_DTO
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string AId { get; set; }
    public string UserId {get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AId"]
    public virtual A_DTO A { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId"]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get a list of object A_DTO but also including property B:

```
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
public IQueryable<A_DTO> GetAllA_DTO()
    {
        string userId = "8b6e9332-7c40-432e-ae95-0ac052904752";

        return context.A_DTO
                    .Include("Bs")
                    .Include("B")
                    .Project().To<A_DTO>()
                    .Where(a => a.Bs.Any(b => b.UserId == userId));
    }
```

How do I dynamically set this property according to set UserId and A_DTO.Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bag of observations in which you may be lucky enough to find your solution:

The `B` property in a code first model will result in there being a foreign key in the database table for A_DTOs that contains a reference to the B_DTOs table. Entity Framework will expect to own the responsibility for filling the `B` navigation property with an object populated with the data from the referenced row in the B_DTOs table, hence you would not be able to change it dynamically.

There is no need to use the Automapper `Project` method if your source type and destination type are the same. In your example they would both appear to be `A_DTO`. Are you sure you don't actually intend to have an entity "A" that is included in the context and "A_DTO" that is mapped from "A" via Automapper? If that is what you really want then you could have code in a `.Select` call mapping `A.Bs.FirstOrDefault(b => b.UserId == userId)` to `A_DTO.B`. However, you would not be able to apply filtering on the basis of the `userId` in an Automapper map.

Without seeing any of the Automapper Map setup code, it is difficult to get an idea of intent here.

As an aside, when using `.Include` it is better, in my opinion, to use the overload that takes an expression. In your case the includes would be rewritten:

```cs
.Include(a => a.B)
.Include(a => a.Bs)
```

Using this overload ensures that you will get compile time errors if you rename a property but fail to update the string in the `.Include` statement.